# How to fix Ruby on Rails in OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@bntzio/how-to-fix-ruby-on-rails-in-os-x-el-capitan-a39af65468e1#.cfhkk718b) to install Ruby on Rails for El Capitan

When I try to install gem install rails -v 4.2.4, i get this error

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Can anyone help?

Comment: What returns `ruby -v`?

Comment: `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with `gem install bundler`. If  it works then try `bundle exec gem install rails -v 4.2.4`.

Comment: i went with another installation altogether, and that one worked. Thanks guys

Comment: Good to know. Thank you